# The set of lengths of geodesics connecting two fixed points on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold and $p\ne q$ in $M$. Put
$$ L=\{\ell(\gamma)~|~\gamma \mathrm{~is ~geodesic ~connecting ~}p\mathrm{~and~} q\}\subset (0,\infty). $$
If $L$ is non-empty, it is true that it cannot have limit points?

Comment: [Something to be read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29298/721644).

Comment: Do you assume the manifold to be complete? What are your thoughts on this question?